# gz log does not work, causes segmentation fault

Tags: gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I launched an empty world with a `waffle_pi`, using the urdf from `turtlebot3_description`

Then in another terminal I run `gz log -d 1 -e`, I got

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<gazebo_log>
<header>
<log_version></log_version>
<gazebo_version></gazebo_version>
<rand_seed>0</rand_seed>
<log_start>0 0</log_start>
<log_end>0 0</log_end>
</header>

Segmentation fault
```

If I run `gz log -d 1` without the `-e`, the terminal that is running the world shows

```
Error [parser_urdf.cc:3474] Unable to call parseURDF on robot model
Error [parser.cc:341] parse as old deprecated model file failed.
```

This happens on both gazebo 7.16.1 with ROS Kinetic and 9.13.2 with ROS Melodic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/26031/gz-log-does-not-work,-causes-segmentation-fault/) by [waffle_pi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/30615/waffle_pi/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2020-10-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You are not supposed to use `-d` with `-e`. `-d` is for starting/stopping recording, and `-e` is for printing the contents of a file. A possible workflow could be:

- `gz log -d 1` to start recording
- `gz log -d 0` to stop recording
- `gz log -e -f <path-to>/state.log` to view the contents of the log

You can ignore the parseUrdf error.

---

Originally posted by [nlamprian](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8391/nlamprian/) with karma: 833 on 2020-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [waffle_pi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/30615/waffle_pi/) on 2020-10-29**:
Thanks! A follow up question: I see that `gz log -d 1` actually makes gazebo publish a message to `~/log/control`, do you think I can write a ROS node, listen to a topic and do the same when received a message? Basically I want to programmatically start/stop recording

**Comment by [nlamprian](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8391/nlamprian/) on 2020-10-30**:
Probably. If you don't want to look into the details, you can also do a system call to `gz log ...`.

**Comment by [waffle_pi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/30615/waffle_pi/) on 2020-10-30**:
turns out it only works when you publish the message to `gazebo/default/log/control` but not `~/log/control`